# Configuration Manager and Command Line

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, cuda, x86-64

I am trying to compile an application that contains CUDA code. I have a 64 bit machine running Windows 7 and have visual c++ 2008 express version (the free version). To be able to use the cuda compiler I followed the steps from [here](http://thewhiteambit.codeplex.com/workitem/11245). The cuda files (with *.cu extension) now compile fine, but the other normal C++ files are using 32 bit because at the drop box on the top (configuration manager) of IDE, it says `Win32`, So I get this error.

```
fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'
```

Note that in the IDE I properly set the target machine for the linker to `MachineX64` (Properties->Configuration Properties->Linker->Advanced->Target Machine). However, looking at the command line, it is something like this.

```
/OUT:"C:\Users\jan\Desktop\gpu\Release\gpu.exe" /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"C:\CUDA\lib64" /LIBPATH:"../../common/lib" /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:"Release\gpu.exe.intermediate.manifest" /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /DEBUG /PDB:"C:\Users\jan\Desktop\gpu\Release\gpu.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /OPT:REF /OPT:ICF /LTCG /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /MACHINE:X64 /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT cudart.lib   C:\CUDA\lib64\cudart.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib
```

Notice, 32 bit version of runtime libraries are being passed to the command line. How can I ask the freaking compiler to use 64 bit. Is this related to the configuration manager. People told me to go to the `configuration manager` and select `new` on the `active solution platform` dropdown and select x64 from there. But the `type or select new platform` dropdown is blank. Please help me. I'm going nuts over this. And note that I have all 64 bit compilation tools in my computer, as I installed the full Windows SDK.

Comment: This looks interesting, http://maliciousattacker.blogspot.com/2008/10/creating-64-bit-applications-with.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the steps given on [this site](http://maliciousattacker.blogspot.com/2008/10/creating-64-bit-applications-with.html).